# AppCompat crash when adding jar

Tags: java, android, jar, android-appcompat, jexcelapi

I have a big problem with Android Studio.
I am actually coding a basic accelerometer and I want to export the data to excel. To accomplish this I've decided to add jexcel api in my project.
Well, the problem is that when I add the jar jxl.jar in my libs folder and I add "compile blablabla jxl.jar" in my build.gradle file, suddenly my gradle sync crashes saying that it cannot load appcompat v7 23.0.0 and all my java files do not recognize appcompat features. I'm almost sure that jexcel api is causing the error but if a remove the jar file, it's too late there's no way back my gradle sync throwns the same error again and again.

When I had these error for the first time I removed all my project and restarted it, the app was running well.

But now it is the third time that a create  new project because of this and now even if I create a new project the bug is still here, so I'm going to cry in front of my laptop, please help, ask me for any file you want to check.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Screenshots of project structure and some errors

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show your  build.gradle and project file structure if possible

Comment: A screenshot of the project structure?

Comment: Try the latest version `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0`

Comment: Throws the same error...

Comment: You don't need to add anything to gradle to compile another jar. The line that says `compile fileTree` handles any jar you drop into the `libs/` folder

Comment: Yes I realised that but even if a add anything to my gradle I have the same error. The problem is that once I've tried to add the jar, even if i erase it, I have the same problem (even if a create a new project...!)

Comment: @RomanPanaget i am unable to reproduce. I added the jxl.jar in the libs folder for my project and used the appcompat-v7 version you mentioned. the project builds fine. try opening terminal in android studio and run `./gradlew clean` then `./gradlew build` and make sure to disable lint check via `lintOptions{abortOnError false}` inside android{} of build.gradle

Comment: I'll try to update Android Studio tomorrow. How did you add jxl.jar? You just dropped it in libs folder?

Comment: Are you behind a network firewall or proxy? That would prevent you from downloading the support library, which seems to be the error.

Comment: I checked something: when I run a new project, the main activity extends Activity by default, and appcompat does not figure in depencies, when I add it manually in module settings, I have the same error, any idea?

Comment: Dependencies*        How I'm supposed to check that, cricket_007? It is true that updating the android support it throws me an exception saying that there is something probably missing in my sdk, i'll try to update the sdk but I reinstalled Android Studio (with the sdk) two days ago

Comment: Did you update the sdk maanger?

Comment: I am updating some sdk files, just a few updates I don't think they will resolve my problem